# Materialize Multiple Select - Show the number of items selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Good Afternoon

I am using materialize multiple select for the user select multiples values, but instead of displaying each value in the input I want to show:

"Selected: 5"

In other words, I want to show the quantity of elements that the user selected, so this way the user will have a clean input, but I've tried many approaches and I didn't achieve this.

I was able to get the amount of items checked by the user, but when I've tried to set using the id of the select or the id of the div/input I didn't achieve this result, practically using the select id I can set the values but this one that I want makes the multiple select stay with the last value selected and using the id of the div doesn't change anything.

Below you will find the code that I've tried.

I hope that someone knows a way to tricky and achieve this.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/dp90tgju/

```
<div id="myInput" class="input-field">
     <select id="filterOptions" multiple>
         <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option>
         <option value="1">Toys</option>
         <option value="2">Comics</option>
         <option value="3">Magazines</option>
         <option value="4">Gym</option>
     </select>
     <label>Filter</label>
</div>



$("#filterOptions").on('change', function() {

        console.log($(this).val());
        if($(this).val().length !== null){
            var numberOfElements = $(this).val().length;
            console.log("Number:" + numberOfElements);

            $(this).val("Selected");
        }

         $("#myInput").val('Selected: 2');

    });
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you provide a working example here https://codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Hi @Morta1

I couldn't reproduce using codesandbox.io but I've done with jsfiddle

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/dp90tgju/